# Fitting a random forest model on a large dataset - few million rows and few thousands columns

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to build a random forest on a slightly large data set - half million rows and 20K columns (dense matrix).

I have tried modifying the hyperparameters such as:

`n_jobs = -1` or iterating over max depth. However it's either getting stopped because of a memory issue (I have a 320GB server) or the accuracy is very low (when i use a lower max_depth)

Is there a way where I can still use all the features and build the model without any memory issue or not loosing on accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion (don't know exactly your case and dataset) you should focus on extract information from your dataset, especially if you have 20k of columns. I assume some of them will not give much variance or will be redundant, so you can make you dataset slightly smaller and more robust to potential overfit. 
Also, you should try to use some dimensionality reduction methods which will allows you to make your dataset smaller retaining the most of the variance.

sample code for pca

[pca gist](https://gist.github.com/bistaumanga/6268985#file-pca-py)

PCA for example (did not mean to offend you if you already know this methods)

[pca wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will give PCA a try and see.